# jQuery Plugin for Drag and Drop Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am going to be starting a project where the site will have multiple pages and the page can be customized as we sit fit on the fly. There will be `blocks` or `widgets` which are things like User Photos, Top 5 ranking, comment box etc and if they are turned on by the user, i want them to be able to place them where they want on the page (per-defined grid that it will snap to).

SO in short, I am looking for a pre-built jQuery plugin that will allow me to move blocks / divs around on a page and then provide me an output of their locations so it will update the database.

Comment: The one requirement is it needs to support IE8 as this is for a company that is still using this version at the moment.

Comment: That just dropped your chances considerably. Btw, you forgot to say that it should be free for commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete solution but rather some possible building blocks. Take a look at the [jQuery UI widgets.](http://jqueryui.com/)

[Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) might do what you want. Take a look at the [visual feedback demo](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback).

[Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) might also work. Or use both (pretty sure you can).